# Freeware Reverb VSTs

Tags: plugins, reverb, vst, freeware

What freeware reverb VSTs can you recommend? Please link to just one reverb per answer so we can vote for favourites.

Useful information for each plugin includes:

- link to download
- features
- screenshot
- platforms supported (e.g. Windows / Mac, VST, RTAS, AudioUnit)
- type of material best suited to
- CPU usage

Comment: I haven't used any of these, but thanks for the info. I now have some new reverbs to play with.

Answer (score 2):

*SIR 1* from [knufinke.de](http://www.knufinke.de/sir/sir1.html) is one of the very few freeware convolution reverbs, allowing for very high quality reverb effects at the cost of fairly high CPU usage. Simply load it up with an impulse response (e.g. one from [NoiseVault](http://noisevault.com/index.php?page=ir-library)) and away you go.

[image: SIR Gui]

- freeware
- Windows VST-Plugin
- works with a fixed latency of 8960 samples (possibly compensated by VST-Host).
- you can adjust predelay, attack-time, length and stereo width of the impulse response
- Stretch (up & downsampling of impulse response)
- FFT EQ (to adjust the frequency spectrum of the impulse-response)
- Auto Gain (automatic volume compensation)
- Dynamic CPU Consumption (use only the CPU power that is needed to get the result)

Aside from CPU usage, the other down-side is a fixed latency of 8960 samples, which should be compensated for by your host. You can buy a paid version if you want zero latency.

Answer (score 1):

*Bootsy EpicVerb* made by [Variety of Sound](http://varietyofsound.wordpress.com/vst-effects/), ([download](http://varietyofsound.wordpress.com/downloads/))

> The “epicVerb” reverberation device aims at both: Tight small room and ambience effect simulation well suited to modern drum and vocal productions up to large “epic” halls as known from high quality outboard gear. This reverbs sound ranges from rather concrete or even edgy up to smooth, transparent and artifact free reverb tails. It is designed for maximum flexibility and usability and to take place as a true high quality stereo main reverb.

[image: EpicVerb Gui]

Answer (score 1):

*Ambience* from Magnus Jonsson of [Smart Electronix](http://magnus.smartelectronix.com/#Ambience) is widely recognised as one of the best freeware reverb VSTs and is no longer donationware - the nag screen is gone. It has lots of configurable parameters and allows you to adjust CPU usage as well. Available as Windows VST and also Mac AU/VST.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Kjaerhus Classic Reverb* was a favourite of mine for some time, and is still available [here](http://www.vstplanet.com/Effects/Effects2.htm), despite the Kjaerhus website no longer being available. It's easy to configure, and the filters are useful to stop it sounding too harsh.

[image: Kjaerhus Class]

Answer (score 0):

*PSP PianoVerb* is a slightly quirky, but very nice sounding reverb. It is available as VST, RTAS and AudioUnit for PC and Mac. It is freeware, although it does require you to authorise it. Product page and download [here](http://www.pspaudioware.com/plugins/reverbs/psp_pianoverb/).

[image: PSP PianoVerb GUI]

> PSP PianoVerb reproduces special kind of reverberation originally provided by piano strings. It generates reverberation using twelve string operators with adjustable damping and decay time. Each of them is tuned to a particular note starting from A(55Hz) to a G#(103.8Hz). The PSP PianoVerb string system can be transposed in the range of +-24 semitones, tuned within a range of +-100 cents and be detuned as well. Transposing to lower octaves produces a bigger and less resonant sound similar to traditional reverbs, while in turn transposing to higher octaves produces a very bright harp-like effect.